# Does a small bolt cutter do OK cutting spokes for a wheel build?

Tags: tools, wheel-building

I'm hoping a cheap bolt cutter will make easier work and put less stress on my cable cutters when cutting and threading spokes for a wheel built. (My hands get knackered pulling on the shortish cable cutters, so 12 inches of leverage would be nice) While the cable cutter did a decent job of keeping the spoke end square-ish, I assume the bolt cutter, which is like a couple chisel points meeting, will give me a chisel-like point on the spoke end.

I'm wondering if anyone's used a bolt cutter for spokes during a build (not a disassembly). I've got a feeling the Hozan threader might not like the non-square end.

Comment: Just to point out: At the factory the spoke’s thread is rolled, not cut. Cutting the thread will be weaker. For cutting the spoke I’d use an angle grinder with a cutting disc.

Comment: The Hozan rolls them too, so far as I can tell.

Comment: There is a different kind of bolt cutter, one that is built into some wire cutting/crimping tools.  Holes for specific sized bolts are threaded into the side of the cutter, such that when the bolt is threaded in it can be sheared off cleanly.  This is the ideal cutter for spokes, but, alas, finding one (in the US) with the thread to match spokes is likely a hopeless cause.

Comment: @Michael - Yeah, a small angle grinder or Dremel-style rotary tool is probably better than most shear-style cutters.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear,if you are cutting spokes to size and threading them yourself, any method of cutting that does not bend the cut end of the spoke is probably OK.

You can use a small file to remove burrs or sharp edges afterwards, and make a chamfer if needed by the thread cutter.

Comment: Agree. I've done this and definitely needed to clean up the cut end of the spoke with a file. Not only does the bolt cutter leave burrs, but it can squish the spoke to be kind of oblong instead of the circle it should be. The Hozan definitely didn't like that.

Comment: I dug out my Hozan manual and it specifically has an admonition not to try using the spoke cut by a pinch-type cutter (bolt or diagonal) unless it's cleaned up square first.

Comment: So now maybe my solution (to the hand thing) requires a cross-cutting plier similar to the Park or Hozan or Ice Toolz, etc., but longer handled. 200mm is the longest I can find.

Comment: if deforming the spoke is an issue, I think i'd use a small hacksaw with a fine tooth blade or a Dremel with a cut-off wheel.

Comment: +1 for the dremel, or a small grinder wheel.   A chop saw might trim multiple spokes at once, if you could fasten them all down.

Comment: @Criggie *A chop saw might trim multiple spokes at once, if you could fasten them all down.*  Yeah, no.  I can imagine someone trying to "fasten" a bundle of 36 spokes by wrapping them tightly in duct tape.  Yeah, the outside ones are fastened nicely to the tape - the inside ones, not so much.  "Look Ma! I'm a voodoo doll!" seems way too likely an outcome.  "But I read it on the intertubez!"  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle True - I was thinking more like lining them all up flat side by side so the butt ends can be lined up with a straight-edge, and then a flat board clamped down on top with a couple of clamps.

Comment: A second at the grinding wheel is all it takes. I believe I've even skipped that step after using a bolt cutter and it's been fine. Also on a side note, cable cutters should never touch spokes. Super hard on the edge.

Comment: Used a cutoff wheel from an angle grinder to cut a couple. Edge was OK, but tough to get a good measurement. Tried one of those grinder jigs that turns it into a chop saw. It was a mess. Rotary tool with cutoff wheel works, but it's slow work cutting 72 that way.

Answer (score 0):

Going to say it won't work *well* unless you clean them up. (Consistent with what the manual say, my Hozan, anyway, likes a nice square cut with no burrs, or I get to do the spoke over again and toss that one in the trash.)

Cleanup with a cross-cut type cutter (Park cable, Pedro's, Ice Toolz, etc.) for me is generally just a very quick swipe across a flat file while spinning, to take off the slight burr. I feel like filing them enough to square them off after using a bolt cutter will probably add a lot more time.

To save the hand, since any of the longer-handled cable cutters I can find are designed for copper and aluminum, I'm just going to lay up some fiberglass/carbon fiber over some tubing and make leverage extensions, then stick those on a $25 pair of cable cutters, since they do cut spokes reliably. They'll probably stop being great for cable, but something's gotta wear out.

I may try marking and vising up half a dozen at a time to hit with the Dremel cutoff wheel and see how that works, timewise.

Comment: I bought a cheap Cal-Hawk wire cutter that's hardened and rated for 1/8" steel wire. I cut about 70 spokes with it and it hasn't got a mark on it. It probably isn't any cleaner than a bolt cutter would be: cut ends need dressing on a file. However, at about $12, the price is right, and the leverage is OK for my use frequency.